# Manage YouTube annotations through YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to manage (create, update) annotations using the YouTube API?

I have a few hundred videos on YouTube that I would like to add annotations to.

Comment: Some code or results of what you tried so far could help you get an answer.

Answer (score 8):

There's an existing feature request for API access to annotations tracked at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=558

I'd recommend "star"ing that feature request to be notified of any updates.

**Update**: It is possible to update InVideo programming annotations, but only those types. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqtuSRe3QLo

Comment: There is an interesting post on that feature request [#35](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=558#c35) which say you can use http://www.youtube.com/annotations/read2?video_id= to get annotation metadata. Unfortunately it 404's :(

Comment: Random unsupported/undocumented endpoints tend to stop working unexpectedly.

Comment: Indeed, always a risk. Should be noted that http://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?cta=1&video_id= works (but is read only as its the information Google'splayer uses).

Answer (score 7):

No, this is not supported.

The [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update) does allow you to create Invideo programming annotations  and [watermarks](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/watermarks/set).

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's just come out, there isn't a documented way of doing anything with annotations via the API yet. I'd be surprised if that kind of support doesn't appear soon, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some time Annotation makes irritate users but sometimes useful to instruct redirect to other topics.

Note: YouTube Discontinued Annotations because it's not working on mobile & second reason is that 70 % user watch YouTube videos on mobile so for better serve youtube took this type of decision.

Please Watch This Video for full clarity: https://youtu.be/Awl1TTUSY78