# Programatically adding annotations to YouTube videos

Tags: youtube-api

I have a project which is using the YouTube API to upload videos to YouTube.
One of the requirements is to be able to add annotations to the video, either at the time of upload, or afterwards. The annotation will contain some text to display, and a link to a URL.
Does anybody know if this is possible using the YouTube API, or some other method.
If it is possible, please provide links with details of how to do this.
Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 1):

No, this was answered already here:
[Manage YouTube annotations through YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463242/manage-youtube-annotations-through-youtube-api)

If you want to do it, you'd have to do it via a browser plug-in or other tricky way such as how YouTubeAnnotations.com does it.